# Unable to grasp my head around go rate package

Tags: go, rate-limiting

I need to rate limit the requests to an API and I'm considering using the native `golang.org/x/time/rate` package for that purpose. In order to fiddling a little bit with its API and make sure that my assumptions are correct, I've created this tests, but it definitely seems that I'm missing something here:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

func TestLimiter(t *testing.T) {
    limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(5),1)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    successful := 0

    for i:=1; i<=10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            if limiter.Allow() {
                successful++
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()

    require.Equal(t, 5, successful)

    // This test fails with
    // Expected :5
    // Actual   :1
}
```

What is the explanation for why this is? Shouldn't the rate limiter allow 5 requests/second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have a data race. Multiple goroutines write `successful` without synchronization: undefined behavior.

You may use the [`sync/atomic`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic) package for an easy and safe counting:

```
limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(5), 1)
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
successful := int32(0)

for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        if limiter.Allow() {
            atomic.AddInt32(&successful, 1)
        }
    }()
}
wg.Wait()

fmt.Println(successful)
```

This will output:

```
1
```

Why? Because you allow 5 events per second, that's 1 event per 0.2 seconds. Launching 10 goroutines and checking will take less than 0.2 seconds, so only one event will be allowed.

If you add 200 ms sleep in the loop, then all will be allowed and output will be `10`:

```
for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
    time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        if limiter.Allow() {
            atomic.AddInt32(&successful, 1)
        }
    }()
}
```

If you add 100 ms sleep, then on average half of them will be allowed and output will be `5`.

What you want probably is allow a burst of 5 with 5 events/sec:

```
limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(5), 5)
```

Using this `limiter` without sleep, you'll also get an output of `5`. That's because 5 events are allowed without hitting the rate limit, and without sleep the rest will not be allowed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer @icza!! Now it is crystal clear to me :-)

Comment: I have an additional doubt regarding burst. Let's say I set a burst of 3 `limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(5), 3)`, and place `time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)` inside a condition `if i > 3 {`. What should be the output then? I think it should be equally `5` as the first three consecutive requests should be allowed due to the burst param, and then it should rate-limit the rest of the requests as usual until reaching the limit of 5. However, the output I'm getting is `6`.

Comment: @beni0888 I get `7` and I think it's fine. You have a bucket with 3 tokens, trying to take away 1 every 100ms, and another one is added to it every 200 ms.

Comment: that's actually weird as I'm continuously getting `6`... Anyways, I'm maybe asking too much, but it would be nice if you could try to explain how the concept of burst actually works, as it seems pretty confusing to me and I think it is not well documented

Comment: @beni0888 `rate.Limiter` implements a token bucket. The doc links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket which describes this in more detail. And also as mentioned in my previous comment: think of it as a bucket with 3 tokens, a new one added every 0.2 seconds (if not full), and one is taken away in every 0.1 seconds (if there's any in it).